# How to deal with time in C++

Tags: c++

I have a question about managing the date and time in c++. I have two classes Plane and Flight in my program.

My Plane will consist data as:

```
string tailNumber;//Plane's unique trait
vector<vector<string>> planeSchedule;//2D string vector to contain plane's depature date and arrival date
```

My Flight class will consist data as:

```
string tailNumber;//Plane's unique trait
string departureDate;
string arrivalDate;
```

In my main class, I will input the value for departureDate and arrivalDate in format: "YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM" such as: `"2019/04/15 10:30" and "2019/04/16 9:30"` (I will use the 24-hour format and time will be GMT).

My question is how do I convert the two strings above to a proper format to store in my planeSchedule, so that I will be able to avoid the time conflict in the planeSchedule.

For example, If the next time I'm adding a flight with departure and arrival date beetween the: `2019/04/15 10:30" and "2019/04/16 9:30"` such as: `"2019/04/15 13:30" and "2019/04/16 7:30"`, I will get an error like "Flight conflict, plane is not available to flight."

My professor recommends using an unsigned long int to store time, but I really do not know where to start to solve this problem. Any help/suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: time is generally stored as an integer that represents the number of units (second, millisecond, 100 nanosecond, etc...) from the epoch. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time#Encoding_time_as_a_number

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono

Answer (score 5):

The go-to place regarding dates and times in C++ is [`<chrono>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono). Some of it has been with us since C++11, some of it we'll see coming with C++20. It works in conjunction with the C-style date and time utilities in [`<ctime>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c), which might even suffice for your purposes.

Trying to handle date / time as either integers or strings, parsing them from input, comparing, and converting them to strings for output, will effectively result in you reimplementing parts of what's already in those headers (a.k.a. "reinventing the wheel").

Comment: I'm flabbergasted that professors actually recommend hackneyed stuff like "using an unsigned long int to store time" as if this were 1970... no wonder people walk away from such courses thinking "C++ is complicated", when it really is not.

Comment: Here's a working preview of the C++20 `<chrono>` bits: https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date  It is in namespace `date` instead of `namespace std::chrono`.

Answer (score 5):

I have two pieces of advice based on long experience with systems that did it badly :-)

The first is to *not* store date and time information as strings or integral values, especially when C++ has very good support for that in `std::chrono`. If you use the correct types, comparisons and manipulations become relatively simple.

Second, make sure you use UTC for all times. You should convert local times to UTC as soon as possible after getting them, and convert back to local as late as possible when presenting them. This will also greatly simplify comparisons.

---

By way of example, here's a complete program which show the simplicity<sup>(a)</sup> in action:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <chrono>

using std::chrono::system_clock;
using std::chrono::duration_cast;

namespace {
    system_clock::time_point getTimePoint(std::string strTime) {
        std::tm myTm = {};
        std::stringstream ss(strTime.c_str());
        ss >> std::get_time(&myTm, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M");
        return system_clock::from_time_t(std::mktime(&myTm));
    }


    void outputTime(const char *desc, system_clock::time_point &tp) {
        std::time_t now = system_clock::to_time_t(tp);
        std::cout << desc
            << std::put_time(std::localtime(&now), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") << "\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    std::string startTime = "2019/04/15 10:30";
    std::string endTime   = "2019/04/16 09:30";

    auto startTp = getTimePoint(startTime);
    auto endTp = getTimePoint(endTime);

    outputTime("Start time: ", startTp);
    outputTime("  End time: ", endTp);

    auto duration = duration_cast<std::chrono::minutes>(endTp - startTp);
    std::cout << "\nThere are " << duration.count() << " minutes between "
        << startTime << " and " << endTime << "\n";
}
```

The output of that program is:

```
Start time: 2019-04-15 10:30
  End time: 2019-04-16 09:30

There are 1380 minutes between 2019/04/15 10:30 and 2019/04/16 09:30
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Yes, the program may *seem* reasonably big but that's just because of the stuff making it a complete program. The `getTimePoint` and `outputTime` functions show how to do the conversion to and from time points, and the *meat* of the simplicity is the line containing `duration_cast` to get the number of minutes between the two time points.

Comment: Can you give me some instructions in using the std::chrono to solve my problem, anything is appreciated.

Comment: @DatTo: That would be easier if you could reduce "your problem" to one single functionality. As it stands, "your problem" is everything from parsing input to storing the values to some not-very-well-defined comparison to output. I.e., "write my program for me", which is not something usually done on Stackoverflow. Pick something specific, and I am sure we could show you some lines of example code.